# In MySQL is it possible to keep the results of a query independent from the results of a subquery?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to output a list of search results to a user.

However which results i choose to display are contingent upon the results of another query.

So:

```
Query 1,
Query 2,

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)
    {
    (IF (Query 2 is xyz)
       {
        Output $row[1]
       }
    }
```

So only query1 results that pass the specific query 2 parameters get printed.

Ultimately, my question is, can i keep 2 separate queries at the same time, by putting their results into different variables? i.e. $result1 and $result2?   or does making a new query override the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$result1 = mysql_query('...');
$result2 = mysql_query('...');
```

And then you can access both of them. E.g.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1/$result2)){ ... }
```

Each variable will store a result object. Calling mysql_query again won't overwrite that because toy have assigned it to a variable. As long as you don't overwrite that variable you will be able to access that specific query result object.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly your question...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Query 1`");

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

$rows = $row['this'];

 if (mysql_numrows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Query 2` WHERE `something` = '$rows' ")) != 0) {
echo $rows;
}

}
```

Comment: please comment if you need help

Comment: I think that works, but, to confirm- so the $row result from the first query is being used as calculation input for the second query and then being outputted only if it meets the criteria, right?

Also, what is the 'this' statement again?

Comment: 'this' is the name of the row

Comment: Also, so would i be able to store the results of 2 different queries in separate variables without interfering with eachother? Sorry if it's already obvious from the post you made, im still new at this.

Comment: ..but you did not select it:)